# How to make all of my IPs works in HyperVM XEN?

Tags: ssh, ip, xen, centos5, hypervisor

I've installed HyperVM on CentOS 5.8 final to make XEN VPS. I have 5 IPs, and added them to an IPPool. They are from *.123 to *.126.
But when I add Virtual machines, just the first one (which indicate to *.123 ip) works well. I mean I can ssh to it by "works well" and when I want ssh to the other ones ( *.124 *.125 ...)  it says :

```
ssh: connect to host *.124 port 22: Connection timed out
```

after a while.

I alos set gateway and netmask as it shows in my server IPAdresses for device `eth0`  (it doesn't make any difference if I set these or not, I get same error).

What should I do now?
Thanks.